# Printf is only printing the first word in a string?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, binary-search

I noticed that my variable input2 is only printing the first word in the string, which is leading to problems with the rest of the program (i.e. not printing the nouns correctly). Any insight on why this is occurring would be appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char *input = strtok(argv[1], " \"\n");
    //printf("%s\n", input);
    int position;
    int check = 0;
    int first = 1;
    while (input != NULL) {
        position = binary_search(verbs, VERBS, input);
        //printf("%s\n", input);
        //printf("%d\n", position);
        if (position != -1){
            if (first){
                printf("The verbs were:");
                first = 0;
                check = 1;
            }
            printf(" %s", input);
        }
        input = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (check == 1){
        printf(".\n");
    }
    if (check == 0){
        printf("There were no verbs!\n");
    }

    char *input2 = strtok(argv[1], " \"\n");
    //printf("%s\n", input2);
    int position2;
    int check2 = 0;
    int first2 = 1;

    while (input2 != NULL) {
        position2 = binary_search(nouns, NOUNS, input2);
        //printf("%s\n", input2);
        //printf("%d\n", position2);
        if (position2 != -1){
            if (first2){
                printf("The nouns were:");
                first2 = 0;
                check2 = 1;
            }
            printf(" %s", input2);
        }
        input2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (check2 == 1){
        printf(".\n");
    }
    if (check2 == 0){
        printf("There were no nouns!\n");
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't the command line arguments already parsed based on whitespace? If so, `argv[1]` will only have a single word in it from the beginning.

Comment: @aardvarkk: Not if it's called like `program 'fly run think type'`.  But it is strange to require that calling convention and not support multiple arguments.

Comment: @aschepler Fair enough!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the string you pass in as the source, so calling `strtok()` with `argv[1]` a second time doesn't act on the original value of `argv[1]`, but only the first token.

You might want to do something like:

```
char* s = strdup(argv[1]);
```

and act on the string `s` o `argv[1]` will be left unchanged - you can process it again later.  However, you'll need to free the duplicated string's memory when you're done with it.